# writev(or pwritev) will conflict with O_DIRECT in c?

Tags: c, io, system-calls

I tried to combine **writev** with **direct IO**. But I got failed when I combined with them.

Below code works, but failed if I add O_DIRECT when open()

I always got "Invalid arguments" when failed.

```
int main(){
    char *str0 = "hello ";
    char *str1 = "world\n";
    struct iovec iov[2];
    ssize_t nwritten;

    iov[0].iov_base = str0;
    iov[0].iov_len = strlen(str0);
    iov[1].iov_base = str1;
    iov[1].iov_len = strlen(str1);

    int fd = open("./foo",O_RDWR|O_CREAT);// will fail if add O_DIRECT
    nwritten = writev(fd, iov, 2);
    printf("num:%ld,%s\n", nwritten, strerror(errno));

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

So I thought it might be **memory alignment** problem, so I adjust them into a memaligned buffer like below:

```
#define BLOCKSIZE 512
int main(){
    char *str0 = "hello ";
    char *str1 = "world\n";
    struct iovec iov[2];
    ssize_t nwritten;

    void *buffer, *buffer1;
    posix_memalign(&buffer, BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE);
    memcpy(buffer, str0, strlen(str0));
    posix_memalign(&buffer1, BLOCKSIZE, BLOCKSIZE);
    memcpy(buffer1, str1, strlen(str1));

    iov[0].iov_base = buffer;
    iov[0].iov_len = strlen(buffer);
    iov[1].iov_base = buffer1;
    iov[1].iov_len = strlen(buffer1);

    int fd = open("./foo",O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_DIRECT);
    nwritten = writev(fd, iov, 2);
    printf("num:%ld,%s\n", nwritten, strerror(errno));

    close(fd);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

But it still failed.

Is there anyway to solve this?

Comment: failed means what ? are you getting seg. fault or any other error ?

Comment: @achal always get "invalid arguments"

Comment: What's your OS?  Linux?  Run your program [under `strace` to see what the actual syscalls made are](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html).  Likely your `writev()` buffers are coalesced into a single non-aligned buffer by `libc` and passed to a single `write()` syscall, which fails with `O_DIRECT` because it's not a page-aligned buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try set the both iov_len to BLOCKSIZE, but the file size would not be strlen(str0) + strlen(str1).

Answer (score 0):

With `DIRECT_IO` there are alignment and size restrictions on the buffers you write from/read into.

That means your write buffer must be properly aligned to the physical block size of the device **and** its size must be dividable by the physical block size of the device.

Whereas the physical block size of the device can be looked up via `/sysfs` and usually is 512 or 4k bytes. Using 4k thus would be a 'safe' choice.

Your `strlen(buffer)` and `strlen(buffer1)` sizes certainly aren't dividable by a physical block size.